# JMeter properties writing concurrently

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, jmeter

I need to [Write to CSV file in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66594355/write-to-csv-file-in-jmeter) *from multiple threads concurrently*. Of course, it'll cause a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), so I'm thinking to take the strategy from [Jmeter write data into excel sheet from multiple thread groups executing concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136991/jmeter-write-data-into-excel-sheet-from-multiple-thread-groups-executing-concurr) :

> A better solution would be passing values from one group to another using **in-memory approach**, to wit without any interim files. You can use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) to define the property

I.e., I plan to define an array in properties and each thread will *append* its record to the array, then write such array out *once* in the end (don't know how yet as [I can't use a tear down thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732172/jmeter-extract-id-variables-from-json-response-and-save-it-in-csv-file-and-us)).

So,

- When each thread try to append to array in properties, does JMeter provide any concurrency protection, or I need somehow protect it myself?
- What's the best approach to write the array out *once* in the end of the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to write some values to JMeter [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) - go for [`sample_variables` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- If you want to write some values to a separate file - consider using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer) plugin. It can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).
- In case if above options don't work for your - you will need to come up with [your own Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html).